# Дедлоки, зачем предлагают интерфейс Lock

Tags: java, многопоточность, deadlock

Вот есть интерфейс Lock и прочие, он может получать блокировки, но прикол в том, что я не понимаю зачем нам вообще это нужно, разве при дедлоках мы не пытаемся наоборот избежать блокировки? Можете мне показать примеры простые или просто объяснить, зачем Lock и подобные ему нужны?

Comment: Мы пытаемся избежать не блокировок, а взаимных блокировок. А блокировки обязательно нужны в тех случаях, когда возможен одновременный доступ к какому-то одному ресурсу (вот попробуйте туалетом воспользоваться всей семьёй одновременно - [без блокировки не обойдётесь](https://imgur.com/aZxU2ms.gif), кому-то придётся ждать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lock по-видимому нужен не для создания дедлоков *(хотя вы можете их сделать с его помощью)*, а для эффективной блокировки потоков. Если вы хотите, чтобы какая-то процедура выполнялась только одним потоком одновременно, то вы можете использовать одну из реализаций Lock.

Вот пример кода с ReentrantLock - реализацией интерфейса Lock:

```
Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
try {
    l.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        // работа с защищенным ресурсом
    } finally {
        l.unlock();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println("Interrupted wait");
}
```

Подробнее про применение вы можете почитать вот [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) или [здесь](http://java-online.ru/concurrent-locks.xhtml#lock)

Answer (score 1):

Примеров много как и объяснений. Не стану заменять своим ответом google лишь предложу понять простую истину. Потоков много, а память одна и общая для всех. Все эти конструкции собраны вокруг одной единственной цели сделать доступ к памяти безопасным. Так чтоб изменение памяти был предсказуемым, а не наоборот.